# Python Arrival Time Estimator display problem

Tags: python

I need some help with a python program that calculates the estimated hours and minutes for a trip. This should include an estimated date/time of departure and an estimated date/time of arrival. However, I can get to display the following:
Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD): 2018-11-29 Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM): 11:15 PM
Enter miles: 500 
Enter miles per hour: 80

Estimated travel time
Hours: 6 
Minutes: 15.0 
Estimated date of arrival: 2018-11-30 
Estimated time of arrival: 05:30 AM

Continue? (y/n): n

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import locale

mph = 0
miles = 0
def get_departure_time():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM):  ")
        try:
            depart_time = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%H:%M %p")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again.")
            continue
        return depart_time


def get_departure_date():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
        try:
            depart_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again. ")
            continue
        return depart_date

def distance():
    while True:
        miles = input("Enter miles to be travelled: ")
        try:
            miles = int(miles)
            if miles <= 0:
                print("Enter a Number Greater than 0.\n")
            else:
                return miles
        except ValueError:
            print("Format Error . Please Try again\n")
            continue

def speed():
    while True:
        speed = input("Enter miles per hour: ")
        try:
            mph = int(speed)
            if mph <= 0:
                print("Enter a Number Greater than 0.\n")
            else:
                return mph
        except ValueError:
            print("Format Error . Please Try again\n")
            continue
        pass

def travel_calculations(miles,mph):
    hours = int(miles/mph)
    minutes = int(((miles/mph)-hours)*60)
    time_travelled = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)



    print("\n\nEstimated travel time")
    print("Hours: ", hours)
    print("Minutes: ", minutes)


def main():
    print("Arrival Time Estimator\n")
    depart_time = get_departure_time()
    depart_date = get_departure_date()

    miles = distance()
    mph = speed()
    travel_calculations(miles,mph)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

enter code here

Comment: What is your question? It needs to be more specific than "I need some help." You haven't even told us what problem you're having.

Comment: How do I go about adding the time delta, so that I can add the delta value to the DateTime value and print it?  For example, Estimated travel time Hours: 6 Minutes: 15.0 Estimated date of arrival: 2018-11-30 Estimated time of arrival: 05:30 AM.